# Multiple indexes in memoir

Tags: memoir, indexing, imakeidx

I am using the memoir class and would like to create two indexes: One for general terms and one for names. Following the documentation in "The Memoir Class for Configurable Typesetting" by Peter Wilson, p. 310 I included

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[names]
```

in my preamble.

```
\index{Wisdom} \index[names]{Alfonso}
```

in the body and

```
\printindex
\printindex[names]
\end{document}
```

at the end.  This gave me no errors, but it only produced one index.

I also tried the imkindex package but this gave me an error about incompatible versions of luatex being used.

What am I doing wrong?

MWE follows

Main file:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\title{Great quotations}
\author{Peter Flom}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[marginpar]{todo}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{makeidx}


\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}

\epigraphwidth 6in

\makeindex
\makeindex[names]

\begin{document}



 \include{AtoC}

\printindex
\printindex[names]
\end{document}
```

A to C file

```
\chapter{A to C}
\section*{Alfonso el Sabio}
  \subsection{On simplicity}\label{Alfonso1} \index{Wisdom} \index[names]{Alfonso}
  \epigraph{%
    Had I been present at the creation, I would have recommended something simpler}{%
    Alfonso el Sabio (Alfonso X) of Castille \\ 1221 -- 1284}

    \subsection{Who was Alfonso?}
```

EDIT: Following the suggestions, I went to the command prompt and entered

```
makeindex [c:\writing\nonfiction\quotes\names.idx]
```

I got the following

```
Input index file [c:\writing\nonfiction\quotes\names.idx] not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
```

but when I look, I see names.idx in the specified spot.

I don't understand the usage note. Are all the things in [] brackets optional?

Comment: Why are you using `[]` and why are you using a full path? Change to the folder where `names.idx` lives and run `makeindex names.idx`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. with `memoir` the `makeidx` is build in, so no need to load it
2. I would not use `titlesec` with `memoir`, see the build in `\setsecheadstyle`    etc
3. You need to manually run `makeindex` (or similar) on all generated `.idx` files. If you use the `latexmk` tool, it will automatically do that.
4. If you want to use automatic index generation via `imakeidx` you need to be aware that it changes the syntax for `\makeindex` such that `\makeindex[names]` needs to be changed to `\makeindex[name=names]`, see the `imakeidx` documentation for more details.

Seems to run fine with `lualatex` under TeXLive 2020

Comment: Thanks.  How do I do #3?  That is, do I put \latexmk  in the preamble?  Or what?

I will look into \setsecheadstyle (although that part is working OK for now)

Comment: No `latexmk` is a script that can do compilations for you, you run it instead of, say, `pdflatex` (`latexmk -pdf`) or `lualatex` (`latexmk -lualatex`), it will then automatically run a number of times to resolve references, citations, index, toc etc. It is what Overleaf is using to compile projects.

Comment: Sorry to be dense here.  I am using WinEdt.  It has a "make index" button. I ran that, and then pdflatex.  This again produced no errors but did not create a name index.

Comment: I don't use WinEdt so I cannot help you. Presumably when you press that button WinEdt runs `makeindex` on `file.idx` (where `file.tex` is your main latex file), but it never touches `names.idx` and thus that index is never made. This is one of the problems with editors, there is no special button to do _unusual compilations_. You'll probably have to use the command line (yes it is scary, but it is a good idea to learn to use it). Or consider item (4)

Comment: It's been a few decades since I used the the DOS prompt, but, I tried it. I got more errors about the file not being found (even though I see the file).

Comment: what **exactly** did you do? And which **exact** errors did you get? Please add this information to your original question as comments are not meant for that stuff. Don't alter your original question, just add this followup to it.